# Get reference to an object within a ListView

Tags: android, reference, onitemclick

Up front: This is my first attempt at an Android app. I'm in that strange place of not knowing what to search for to find the answer to my question.

What I have accomplished is:

- Created a custom class *myCustomClass* with properties of 'title' and 'youTubeUrl'
- Created an ArrayList<myCustomClass>
- Added multiple elements to ArrayList<myCustomClass>
- Created a custom ArrayAdapter and attached it to the the arraylist.
- Added an onItemClickListener to the custom ArrayAdapter.

All of that works good. I would like to show the title in the ListView and then when the user clicks the list view item, I'd like to get a reference to the youtubeUrl property.

Here's what I have for the adapter code:

```
MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.my_list, elements);
myList.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: show myListAdapter.java source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `position` property in `onItemClick` to go back to your data source and find the relevant item.  From there you should be able to retrieve the Url.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the youTubeUrl with this code:
`String youTubeUrl = elements.get(position).youtubeVideo;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), youTubeUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 0):

As another poster implied, it depends on what you are using in your adapter.  Assuming it's MyCustomClass.  You can do something like this in your onItemClick method:

```
MyCustomClass selection = (MyCustomClass) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It might make the code more readable in the future.

Am I correct in assuming that you code would end up getting the same data as this:
`MyCustomClass selection = (MyCustomClass) elements.get(postion);`

Comment: I believe so.  One note - adapters are often dynamic things so I probably wouldn't reference elements from within onItemClick(). If elements is marked final and you know for certain that you won't be changing your adapter's model it wont cause a problem but its still not a good idea.